# Does YouTube Data API billing change if the APIs are called from GCP server or AWS server?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm building an Android app which embeds YouTube videos. I'm confused on how the billing works for the YouTube Data API v3. Is it dependent on whether the APIs are called from GCP server or AWS server?

Answer (score 17):

The YouTube Data API, is a free API Google does not charge you for accessing this API.  You are free to use it.    Therefore no billing account is needed in order to access this API.

You do have a quota which limits the number of request that you can make to the API over a period of time.

Useful links

- [Quota cost calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)
- [YouTube API and cost based quota demystified](https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What happens post 10k quota is over? Will I be able to still hit the API for a price or it just stops working?

Comment: If you go over your 10k quota you will get a **quotaExceeded (403)** error message and wont be able to use the API again until mid night west cost USA time.    If you think you will hit it you should consider applying for a quota extension.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will increase your own reputation as well.

Comment: @daimto is it possible to increase this quota by paying for it?

Comment: You can request more quota.   I am not sure if you have to pay for it.

Comment: You don't need to pay for quota extension. You need to fill out a form and the review team will take a close look at your project. After that they will send you a list of changes you need to implement if any before your quota extension.